# loading different scss file based on current language - nuxt

Tags: vue.js, sass, frontend, nuxt.js, bidirectional

i'm trying to implement rtl/ltr in my nuxt application.
this is my project structure

```
|--assets
   |--scss
     |--**/*.scss
     |--bundle.scss
     |--bundle-rtl.scss
```

so styles are compiled into the bundle and bundle-rtl normally.
the problem is this .. how can i switch between theses two scss files without changing them manually within my nuxt.config (automatically change the scss file when the language is changed).
among these files is a mixin file with many mixins related to rtl and ltr switching so i need to use them in each vue file that i have. which is why i can't just compile them to css (with gulp or webpack for example) and include them in head.
aside from all of this, is this the best way to implement ltr/rtl in nuxt or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should write modern CSS that takes this into account rather than having a duplicate. This will have the benefit to also be usable by other languages.

Check this awesome article: https://css-tricks.com/building-multi-directional-layouts/

Comment: wow! ... that's actually a very good solution .. i mean ill lose all of my mixins in the template files but its better than the alternative.

Comment: For me, it's still the cleanest solution and the more performant one because it will be pretty messy to have it handled per `.scss` file. You could make some kind of dynamic styling directly into your templates but this will also be messy/ugly. Or at least, you may need to load a small `.scss` file on top of your usual one just to make a few changes IMO.

Comment: Well tbh i dont have an alternative, i dont even think there is an alternative tbh.

Comment: Not a non ugly one yeah.